# Isothermal coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question

Is there an application or interest in studying the isothermal surfaces where the metric is $ds^2=E*(du^2+dv^2)$ and where $E>0$ is an harmonic function?

I know that this metric is a special kind of Liouville's metric, but is there a possible application?

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you want $E$ harmonic? Or $E = e^f$ with $f$ harmonic?

Comment: Yes $E$ harmonic... $E=e^f$ where $f=logE$ with $E$ harmonic.

Comment: In this way $f_u$$_u$+$f_v$$_v$$=-(f_u^2+f_v^2)$

Comment: No one has any idea?